# What is a seed in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm a beginner in TensorFlow, and I came across a parameter called `seed` in most of the functions. Also, it comes as the only parameter in some functions such as `tf.set_random_seed(seed)`. Is this term `seed` specific to tensorflow? I believe I've surfed the TensorFlow documentation enough but couldn't find a solid answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The term "seed" is an abbreviation of the standard term ["random seed"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed).

TensorFlow operators that produce random results accept an optional seed parameter. If you pass the same number to two instances of the same operator, they will produce the same sequence of results. If you not pass a number to such an operator, it will produce different results on each execution.

Answer (score 6):

This is not a tensorflow specific term, in fact almost any programming language have a seed for random generators, with a seed you make sure that you can reproduce your results when using random generators(using the same seed two times, would result in the same random number).